# How to get table id using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, html-table

In my Java program I have a `List<DemoTable>`.

```
List<DemoTable> demotable = new ArrayList<DemoTable>();
```

`DemoTable` is a class with `id`,`name`,and `details` variables.

I display these details using Jquery..

```
<table>
  <c:forEach items="${modalAttribute.demotable}" var="demo">
    <tr class="M_row_bg M_read">
         <td><input type="checkbox" id="isDelete"/></td>
         <td><label for="name">${demo.name}</label></td>
             <td><label for="totalExperience">${demo.details}</label></td>
       </tr>
  <c:forEach>
</table>
```

Data will be displayed correctly ... but when check box is clicked I want to get Table row id:

```
$("#isDelete").click(function(){
if (this.checked){
   alert('checked');
   alert(demo.id);
} else {
    alert('unchecked');
}
} );
```

I expect this alert to give the `DemoTable` id, but this alert does not show. Also, this click only works for the first row of the table.

How can I get the DemoTable id when I click the check box?

What does my code need to work with each row of table click event, not just the first row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you're using `#isDelete` multiple times in the table. This is illegal, and the reason your code only works on the first row.  Use a class instead.
2. your table rows don't even *have* an ID.  They do however have an implicit index.
3. you should give your table an ID
4. you can use "event delegation" and just register a single click handler on a common parent element (i.e. the table) which then uses event bubbling to figure out which actual element was clicked.  This can be more efficient than registering the exact same event handler explicitly on every matching element.

Try this instead:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', '.isDelete', function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').index();  // row within table (0 based)
    }
});
```

Comment: #myTable means Table tag id?... and is it possible to maintain a hidden values in Table?

Comment: yes `<table id="myTable">`.  As for hidden values, sure, that's possible.

Comment: Ok i'm maintain my class id as hidden ...<input class="hiddenId" type="hidden" value="${demo.id}"/>.. this is working ? if working how to get hidden tag vlaue in click event.

Comment: You would be better to use `<tr data-id="${demo.id}"/>` and then using `$(this).closest('tr').data('id')` to extract it.  Don't use hidden form fields for values that aren't going to be sent to a server.